# java, hibernate - object references an unsaved transient instance

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm trying to persist a `Comment` with hibernate. Besides an id and a body, a `Comment` has an user and an issue property. The following throws an
`org.hibernate.TransientObjectException` saying that I should save `User` before flushing.

```
   public static long saveComment(Comment comment) {

    long ret;

    try (Session ses = factory.openSession()) {
        ses.beginTransaction();
        ses.save(comment.getUser());
        ses.save(comment.getIssue());
        ret = (long) ses.save(comment);
        ses.getTransaction().commit();
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Changing `ses.save(comment.getUser());` to `ses.persist(comment.getUser());` results in a `org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException` saying that `User` is detached. I'm confused, as far as I understand, an object in hibernate is either transient or detached, but here it seams it's both.

I already tried different cascading types on `User`s `OneToMany` annotations, currently they are set to `PERSIST`, witch seams to be what I want. Also, as far as I understand it, `Comment` should have no `cascade` value, since `User` and `Issue` own the `Comment`.

Below is the code that gets the User and the code that calls `saveComment`.

```
public static Response create(String body) throws IOException {
    Map<String, Object> map = new ObjectMapper()
            .configure(DeserializationFeature.USE_LONG_FOR_INTS, true)
            .readValue(body, Map.class);
    User creator;
    Issue issue;

    try {
        creator = Repository.getUserById((long) map.get("user_id"));
    } catch (NoResultException ex) {
        return Response.status(404).entity(ex.getMessage()).build();
    }
    try {
        issue = Repository.getIssueById((long) map.get("issue_id"));
    } catch (NoResultException ex) {
        return Response.status(404).entity(ex.getMessage()).build();
    }

    Comment comment = new Comment();
    comment.setBody((String) map.get("body"));
    comment.setIssue(issue);
    comment.setUser(creator);
    creator.addComment(comment);
    issue.addComment(comment);

    long id = Repository.saveComment(comment);

    return Response.created(URI.create("/comment/"+id)).build();
}

public static User getUserById(long id) {
    User ret;

    try (Session ses = factory.openSession()) {
        ses.beginTransaction();
        ret = (User) ses.createQuery(
                "from User u where u.id = :id")
                .setParameter("id", id)
                .getSingleResult();
        ses.getTransaction().commit();
    }

    return ret;
}
```

EDIT: The User and Comment entities.

```
package de.phs.issues.model;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIdentityInfo;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIdentityReference;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.ObjectIdGenerators;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationFeature;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationFeature;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.EqualsAndHashCode;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

@Entity
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(exclude = {"issues", "comments"})
@Table(name="`user`")
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "id", scope = User.class)
public class User {

    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String name;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private long id;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "creator", cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JsonIdentityInfo(generator=ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property="id")
    @JsonIdentityReference(alwaysAsId=true)
    private Set<Issue> issues = new HashSet<>();

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JsonIdentityInfo(generator=ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property="id")
    @JsonIdentityReference(alwaysAsId=true)
    private Set<Comment> comments = new HashSet<>();

    public String toJson() throws JsonProcessingException {
        return new ObjectMapper()
                .enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT)
                .writeValueAsString(this);
    }

    public static User fromJson(String json) throws IOException {
        return new ObjectMapper()
                .configure(DeserializationFeature.USE_LONG_FOR_INTS, true)
                .readValue(json, User.class);
    }

    public boolean addIssue(Issue issue) {
        issue.setCreator(this);
        return issues.add(issue);
    }

    public boolean removeIssue(Issue issue) {
        issue.setCreator(null);
        return issues.remove(issue);
    }

    public boolean addComment(Comment comment) {
        comment.setUser(this);
        return comments.add(comment);
    }

    public boolean removeComment(Comment comment) {
        comment.setUser(null);
        return comments.remove(comment);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("User{id=");
        sb.append(id);
        sb.append(" ,name=");
        sb.append(name);
        sb.append(", issues=[");
        String issue_ids = issues.stream()
                .map(Issue::getId)
                .map(l -> Long.toString(l))
                .flatMap(s -> Stream.of(",", s))
                .skip(1)
                .collect(Collectors.joining());
        sb.append(issue_ids);
        sb.append("], comments=[");
        String comment_ids = comments.stream()
                .map(Comment::getId)
                .map(l -> Long.toString(l))
                .flatMap(s -> Stream.of(",", s))
                .skip(1)
                .collect(Collectors.joining());
        sb.append(comment_ids);
        sb.append("]}");
        return sb.toString();
    }
}

package de.phs.issues.model;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIdentityInfo;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIdentityReference;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.ObjectIdGenerators;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationFeature;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationFeature;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.EqualsAndHashCode;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.io.IOException;

@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(exclude = {"user", "issue"})
@Entity
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "id", scope = Comment.class)
public class Comment {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private long id;
    private String body;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JsonIdentityInfo(generator=ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property="id")
    @JsonIdentityReference(alwaysAsId=true)
    private User user;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JsonIdentityInfo(generator=ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property="id")
    @JsonIdentityReference(alwaysAsId=true)
    private Issue issue;

    public String toJson() throws JsonProcessingException {
        return new ObjectMapper()
                .enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT)
                .writeValueAsString(this);
    }

    public static Comment fromJson(String json) throws IOException {
        return new ObjectMapper()
                .configure(DeserializationFeature.USE_LONG_FOR_INTS, true)
                .readValue(json, Comment.class);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("Comment{body=");
        sb.append(body);
        sb.append(", id=");
        sb.append(id);
        sb.append(", user=");
        sb.append(user.getId());
        sb.append(", issue=");
        sb.append(issue.getId());
        sb.append("}");
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you are not saving the Comment object anywhere.

Comment: Just make sure your child object also not null . It usually happen because of that.

Comment: I added some println's bevor `long id = Repository.saveComment(comment);`, none of the object were null. I save the comment in `ret = (long) ses.save(comment);`.
`

Comment: Please show your User and Comment entities. It may be that you are cascading comments from User persist, which cascades to user as per your code. If this is the case just leave the cascading in one side of the mapping and persist the owning entity